# As explained here.../ As is explained here

Tags: grammaticality, as

I would like to know which of two beginnings of a phrase

*As explained here.../ As is explained here...*

is grammatically correct? I just found a book where "As explained here,..." is used, but this sounds strange to me, am I wrong?

Comment: I think "As explained here" is the best usage.Please go through the link [AS IS](http://www.yourdictionary.com/as-is)

Comment: @anish That's a different "as is".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case of "As explained here", "explained" is used in role of adjective. It is a common, correct construct. It's the same construct as

> "As a young scout, you are entitled to a discount ticket".

The other construct makes it into a complex sentence:

> Since you are a young scout, you are entitled to a discount ticket."

Both constructs are correct, but the first one flows more naturally. Just watch out that you make the subjects match:

> As a young scout, a llama bit me when I was on a trip at a zoo garden."

No, the llama was not a young scout at that time.